# Android - Best way to watch a SQLite database for new rows and then perform a task

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, handler, semaphore

New Android app "developer" here, working on my first app.
As the title suggests I am trying to find the best way to handle updates to my SQLite database and perform an action based on new rows.

New rows can be added one of two ways:
1) a content observer that auto-adds new enteries when a photo is taken
2) via the share intent

*Only my app can add entries to the database.*

Right now I have an asynctask that loops in the background once every 1000ms, checks if a new image is added to the database, checks a couple variables and if everything is good to go it performs a HttpPost task.

This works as expected.

I come from a web dev history with very minimal threading experience. I've read articles on [threads](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), [Semaphores](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and [handlers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) but I'm really struggling on making sense of them and which would be best for my needs or if what I am currently doing is ok.

Does `Thread.sleep(1000);` prevent the device from entering deep sleep? Thus killing the battery.

What I am really looking for is some guidance, possibly some examples, I like to think of my self as a quick learner but my lack of experience with threading is preventing me from truly understanding what is *best* for what I am trying to accomplish.

Images are added to the database using the following method:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ...

    // Adding new Image
    public void addImage(Image image) {
        Log.d(TAG, "adding image: "+image._uri);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_URI, image._uri);  // image uri
        values.put(KEY_TRIES, image._tries); // upload tries
        values.put(KEY_UPLOADED, image._uploaded); // upload status
        values.put(KEY_DATE_ADDED, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        values.put(KEY_DATE_UPLOADED, image._date_uploaded);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_IMAGES, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "image added");
    }
}
```

Comment: What fills the SQLite database?

Comment: public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { ... }

Comment: Yes, but are the updates external or is it only your app that modifies the database?

Comment: sorry misunderstood your question. yes, only my app adds them to the database.

Comment: Is your app handling the task of taking of a photo?

Comment: no, it gets the photos from a content observer or when it is shared to

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you already have an event when a new content relevant to your app appears. Launch an upload if a connection is available. If there is no connection available just cache it in the database (by using a similar database structure or using a column to indicate upload status, say Unix Epoch for cached photos).

From then on you may just add an inexact alarm through AlarmManager that tries to upload cached data.

Comment: well, the other thing i need it to do is after a device reboot i need it to look if there are any images pending. would this answer address that too?

Comment: After a reboot you'd need to reregister the alarms. After the device boots up it sends `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. A custom receiver could reregister them. The app would need a specific permission. If a user would surely navigate to your app, you could reregister alarms to avoid elevating permissions.